# calibration and registration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui

And select /camera/driver

Enable the depth_registration checkbox

Dose this registration display an alternative to openni for Extrinsic Calibration?

unless, what is the relation between calibration and registration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36956/calibration-and-registration/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Registration aligns the depth data and color data to output colorized points.  It uses the factory measured intrinsic calibration of the sensor.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0